# Laravel View Composer with Repository is not working;

Tags: php, laravel, view, repository-pattern

I'm using a package with cities and countries in my Laravel project. I set up a repository pattern to use this cities data. My plan is to send the cities data to the register view or any other view I want. In the example here I want to send to the project.create page. I tested the repository and when I look through the controller, I can pass the data to the view and print it with dd(). There is no problem with this. Now I want to send this data to a view i want via viewcomposer.

**First of all, I wrote a ComposerServiceProvider.php file as follows**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(
            'project.create',
            'App\View\Composers\LocationComposer'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Then I wrote the composer file, which is as follows:**

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Composers;

use App\Repository\Eloquent\LocationRepository;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class LocationComposer
{
    /**
     * @var LocationRepository
     */
    public $locationlist;

    /**
     * LocationComposer constructor.
     * @param LocationRepository $locations
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(LocationRepository $locations)
    {
        $this->locationlist = $locations->getAllCities();
    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\View\View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('cities', $this->locationlist);

    }
}
```

But the data does not pass to the view I want.

[this is the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Zrn.png)

**Things I've tried and done:**
-I registered the composerserviceprovider via app config.
-I ran php artisan config:clear
-I tried to send to other views Welcome, register etc.

I suspect I am not invoking the repository correctly into composer.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the error?

Comment: Data dont pass the view...

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also contain your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: ok sorry i thought i wrote all the details i am editing it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probabaly you didn't add `App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class` into your `config/app.php` file. All additional service providers need to be added into `providers` array of `config/app.php` file.